# Simplest portfolio optmization under transaction costs

Tags: finance, portfolio-optimization, transaction-costs

I've been studying portfolio optimization trying to go step by step.
After seeing much of Markowitz and Merton's work (Although I still don't get all of it), I would like to have acquire more knowledge about theories that introduce transaction costs.

I've read somewhere that it first begun with Magill and Constantinides ? 
Is it the simplest one out there ? Should I start by that or would you advise me to see something else ?
Can anyone recommend a reference where I could study the Magill model ?

Thank you !

Comment: Are you looking for Magill & Constantinides (1976) ? http://faculty.chicagobooth.edu/george.constantinides/documents/JET_1976.pdf

Comment: I am not an expert on this (and it is quite a difficult area). There are various formulations depending on what type of costs are assumed (fixed, proportional, etc.). You can get a brief overview in the Wikipedia entry for Merton's Problem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merton's_portfolio_problem#Extensions